# Detect changes in the value of other objects referenced in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a feature that detects a change in the value of another field object reference.

For example, there is an A object, and the B object contains A.
The A object is notified by OnValidate when the field of the A object has changed.
At this time. Is there any way that "B" can detect the change of "A"?

This feature is only required in the Editor and does not include code in Runtime.

```
public class A : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string team;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Debug.Log($"My team name has been changed to {team}.");
    }
}

public class B : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public A a;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Debug.Log($"A changed.");
    }

    // How can I detect changes to A and call this functions?
    private void OnATeamChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log($"A's team name has been changed to {a.team}.");
    }

    private void OnADestroyed()
    {
        Debug.Log($"A is missing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you could have a flag in `A` e.g. `public bool isChanged;` and in `B` check it e.g. in `Update`.. or directly store the old values and compare them to the current values

Comment: @derHugo This feature should also work with ScriptableObject. It is notified immediately when the value changes, like observer pattern.

Comment: You said its enough in the editor .. so you should get into custom editor scripting: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html what you would want to register to would be the https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-hierarchyChanged.html or maybe https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-projectChanged.html

Comment: @derHugo I tried with the Custom Editor. How can I detect that an object is reset?

Comment: You could use [Reset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html). One thing that I didn't understand yet: Do you want `B` to work in general or is it ok to have to implement additional stuff in `A` as well?

Comment: I think code can be added to A or B to implement this functionality, without adding a public members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also propose to use events but be careful how and when you register and remove listeners!

```
public class A : ScriptableObject
{
    // You don't need [SerializeField] 
    // public properties are serialized anyway
    public string team;

    public event Action onChanged;
    public event Action onReset;
    public event Action onDestroyed;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Debug.Log($"My team name has been changed to {team}.");

        if(onChanged == null) return;
        onChanged.Invoke();
    }

    // This is called on reset
    // But if you override this you have to set
    // The default values yourself!
    private void Reset()
    {
        team = "";

        if (onReset == null) return;
        onReset.Invoke();
    }

    // Called when object is destroyed
    private void OnDestroyed()
    {
        if(onDestroyed == null) return;
        onDestroyed.Invoke();
    }
}
```

But now in `B` I would not add the listener on `Awake` since this adds it after every recompile and multiple times! Instead don't forget to "clean up" all listeners you ever add to avoid getting NullReferenceExceptions:

```
public class B : ScriptableObject
{
    // You don't need [SerializeField] since public properties
    // are serialized anyway
    public A a;

    // Internal for removing listeners later
    private A lastA;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Apparently something else was changed
        if(a == lastA) return;

        Debug.Log("reference a changed");

        // Unregister listeners for old A reference
        if(lastA)
        {
            lastA.onChanged -= OnAChanged;
            lastA.onReset -= OnAReset;
            lastA.onDestroyed -= OnADestroyed;
        }

        // Register listeners for new A reference
        // Note that it is allways possible to remove listeners first
        // even if they are not there yet
        // that makes sure you listen only once and don't add multiple calls
        if(a)
        {
            a.onChanged -= OnAChanged;
            a.onReset -= OnAReset;
            a.onDestroyed -= OnADestroyed;

            a.onChanged += OnAChanged;
            a.onReset += OnAReset;
            a.onDestroyed += OnADestroyed;
        }

        lastA = a;
    }

    // Make allways sure you also remove all listeners on destroy to not get Null reference exceptions
    // Note that it is allways possible to remove listeners even if they are not there yet
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(!a) return;

        a.onChanged -= OnAChanged;
        a.onReset -= OnAReset;
        a.onDestroyed -= OnADestroyed;
    }

    private void OnAChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log("A was changed");
    }

    private void OnAReset()
    {
        Debug.Log("A was reset");
    }

    private void OnADestroyed()
    {
        Debug.Log("a was destroyed");
    }
}
```

---

Small optional change if you want

If you want additionally to be able to register other listeners in the Inspector the same way you do for `Button`s you could simply exchange the

```
public event Action xy;
```

with

```
public UnityEvent xy;
```

and remove the `if(xy == null)` checks.

You would than also replace

```
a.onChanged -= OnAChanged;
a.onChanged += OnAChanged;
```

by

```
a.onChanged.RemoveListener(OnAChanged);
a.onChanged.AddListener(OnAChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add an event

```
public class A : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string team;
    public Action RaiseChangeName;
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Debug.Log($"My team name has been changed to {team}.");
        if(RaiseChangeName != null) { RaiseChangeName(); }
    }
}

public class B : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public A a;
    void Awake()
    {
         a.RaiseChangeName += OnATeamChanged;
    }

    // How can I detect changes to A and call this functions?
    private void OnATeamChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log($"A's team name has been changed to {a.team}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: But be very careful how and when to register listeners and also don't forget to remove them to avoid NullReferences